# OpenCV understanding Greyscale

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I'm confused as to how OpenCV does its Colour to Greyscale conversion. If I send it an image consisting only of patches of pure Red, Pure Green and Pure Blue (e.g. {255,0,0}) I would expect it to convert this to a consistent grey of value 255/3 = 85, but this isn't so.

I tried:

```
IplImage* src;
src=cvLoadImage("image.bmp", 0)
val = cvGetReal2D( src, y, x );
```

This gives confusing output that converts pure red to 147, pure green to 200, and pure blue to 95 (I think I got the order right there). Greys are converted as you would expect (e.g. {127,127,127} --> 127).

I then came across cvCVTColor function and this seems to use the human eye response to weight the conversion (Grey = 0.299*Red + 0.587*Green + 0.114*Blue):

```
IplImage *im_rgb  = cvLoadImage("image.bmp");
IplImage *im_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im_rgb),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
cvCvtColor(im_rgb,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
val = cvGetReal2D( im_gray, y, x );
```

I have successfully converted as I'd like by splitting the channels:

```
IplImage* red_channel = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width, src->height), 8, 1);
IplImage* green_channel = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width, src->height), 8, 1);
IplImage* blue_channel = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width, src->height), 8, 1);
cvSplit( src, blue_channel , green_channel, red_channel , NULL);
val = ( cvGetReal2D( red_channel, y, x ) + cvGetReal2D( green_channel, y, x ) + cvGetReal2D( blue_channel, y, x ) ) / 3;
```

But I would like to learn from this what OpenCV does to convert to greyscale when using cvLoadImage and/or is there a single function I can use to convert without the human eye response (ie Grey = (Red+Green+Blue)/3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a single function, but you can just split the channels, multiply each channel with its coefficient and sum up all channels in a single image.

c++ syntax would be:

```
int main()
{
  cv::Mat color = cv::imread("lena.jpg");
  cv::Mat red(color.rows, color.cols, CV_8UC1);
  cv::Mat green(color.rows, color.cols, CV_8UC1);
  cv::Mat blue(color.rows, color.cols, CV_8UC1);

  std::vector<cv::Mat> output;
  output.push_back(blue);
  output.push_back(green);
  output.push_back(red);

  cv::split(color,output);

  float r = 0.0f;
  float g = 0.2f;
  float b = 1.0f - (r + g);
  cv::Mat graySelf = r*red + g*green + b*blue;
  // could be computed with two calls of cv function addWeighted() in the same way!


  cv::Mat grayCV;
  cv::cvtColor(color,grayCV, CV_RGB2GRAY);

  cv::namedWindow("cv"); cv::imshow("cv", grayCV);
  cv::namedWindow("self"); cv::imshow("self", graySelf);
  cv::namedWindow("color"); cv::imshow("color", color);

  cv::imwrite("cv.png", grayCV);
  cv::imwrite("self.png", graySelf);
  cv::waitKey(-1);


  return 0;
}
```

giving images:

color:

[image]

openCV:

[image]

self:

[image]

in cvtColor, opencv 2.4.4 c++ internally uses this function snippet in imgproc/src/color.cpp I guess:

```
int scn = srccn;
float cb = coeffs[0], cg = coeffs[1], cr = coeffs[2];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++, src += scn)
    dst[i] = saturate_cast<_Tp>(src[0]*cb + src[1]*cg + src[2]*cr);
```

Comment: Thanks Micka, a very comprehensive answer, with useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion formula from color to grayscale is not (R+G+B)/3

Find out the right one and why is it so on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale)

Comment: I understand that in many applications you would wish to use the human eye response to weight the conversion, but in mine I want it to be as sensitive to blue as it is to green or red.

Comment: Then write your own conversion. OpenCV follows the standard. There is no need for it to implement a conversion with no practical meaning. But I really doubt you need the R,G,B average in your project.